# Adding TFS task with priority, assigned to using c#

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to create a tfs task using c# code.  I am able to add task with the below code.
But I am unable to add assignedto, keywords, priority etc through this. I did not find related properties in workItemType object.

I tried Fields["Keywords"] etc but it did not work for me. Any pointers please

```
private static readonly Uri TfsServer = new Uri("my tfs url");
        static readonly TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsServer);
        static readonly WorkItemStore workItemStore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        static readonly Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["my project name"];
        static readonly WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Task"];

WorkItem tfsTask = new WorkItem(workItemType)
            {
                Title = "Test Title",
                //assignedto,
                State = "Proposed",
                //substatus ="Not Started",
                AreaPath = @"my path",
                IterationPath = @"my iteration path",
                //Keywords ="my keyword",
                //prioity=3

                Description = "newVcDescription"
           };

          tfsTask.Save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the value for work item field from `new WorkItem(workitemType){}`, you can only set the value for these fields provided by intellisense:
[image]

For other fields, you can set the value like this:

```
tfsTask.Fields["Priority"].Value = "4";
tfsTask.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = "XXX";
tfsTask.Tags = "tag1;tag2";
tfsTask.Save();
```

Answer (score 2):

So not all standard attributes of tfs can be called like that. Not 100% sure in C# but in powershell i would have to do something like this.

```
$proj = $ws.Projects["Scrum Test"]
$ProductBacklogWorkItem=$proj.WorkItemTypes["Product Backlog Item"]
$pbi=$ProductBacklogWorkItem.NewWorkItem()


// stadard attribute
$pbi.Description = $SRLongDescription

// nonstandard
$pbi["Assigned to"] = $SROwner

// custom elements
$pbi["Custom.CD.ExternalReferenceID"] = $SRTicketId
```

I know its a different way of calling but thought it might be helpful to understand how TFS looks at the work item attributes.